# How to fetch all objects from CEP (ESPER) framework for a particular time

Tags: esper

I have a OrderEvent class which has 2 property:
String itemName, double price

My requirement is : ESPER framework will hold OrderEvent objects for 10 sec. for this I written below EPL query:

**select itemName, sum(price) from OrderEvent.win:time_batch(10 sec).std:unique(itemName) group by itemName**

This is working fine.

But I wants to run above query at every 1 sec and display the all item name and sum(price) means all relevant EventBean[] objects should be come in listener.

Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a rolling 10 seconds? In this case you'd want to use a time window not a time batch window. There is an "output every 1 sec". So the query could be "select itemName, sum(price) from OrderEvent.win:time(10) group by itemName output all every 1 sec"